# c++ Constructor With 1 string parameter into 3 attributes

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Some backstory...
For a homework assignment in my Data struct and algorithms,(early on) I have to create a class definition and implementation that models a store item, formatted with Part number, department code, and price. I have it mostly done except for one constructor overload that I can't seem to figure out how to start.  
 Sample of what I have so far.

```
/** Default Construct*/
Item() : Part_Num("------"), Dep_Code("---"), item_Price(0){}
/** First 3Param Constructor*/
Item(std::string partNum, std::string dept, std::string priceStr): 
Part_Num(partNum),Dep_Code(dept), item_Price(stod(priceStr)){}
/** Second 3Param Constructor*/
Item(std::string partNum, std::string dept, double priceD) :
    Part_Num(partNum), Dep_Code(dept), item_Price(priceD) {}
```

The issue I have, is that I need to create a one parameter constructor that takes a string, in the format of

> BN3782 ELE 87.25

and splits it into the correct data members. I have an idea for the parsing, but I don't know how to define the constructor to start. Just a push in the right direction would be appreciated. This is my first post and I'm not great at explaining, so let me know if anyone needs any additional information.  
I have tried

```
Item(std::string data) : Part_Num(data), Dep_Code(data), item_Price(data){}
```

But that has yet to work with my code, and I'm not sure why it would... (was suggested on another forum).

EDIT: I got it working with pm100 suggestion, Here's a code sample I got working for anyone in the future having the same problem.

```
Item(std::string line) {
    item_Data = line;
    line = removeSpaces(item_Data);
    Part_Num = line.substr(0, 6);
    Dep_Code = line.substr(6, 3);
    item_Price = stod(line.substr(9));
}
```

Comment: define a constructor that takes one string argument `Item(std::string &valueStr)`

Comment: `Item(std::string partString) { your code here }`?

Comment: Item(std::string data) : <do I not need the data members here?> {}

Comment: I see your confusion. you cannot use a initialization list since you have to parse the string. Assign the field values in the code of the consructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code the field assignments

```
Item(std::string &valstr)
{
    Part_Num = <parsed bit of string>;
    Dep_Code = <a different part of the string>;
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I had tried that before, but had gotten a lot of errors, good to know I was in the right place though. There was also posts elsewhere that made me think otherwise.

Comment: if you get stuck post a new question

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, if you like you can still use the initilizer list. You just need to do the parsing somewhere. Lets say you have a:

```
std::string nth_part(int n,std::string s) { ... }
```

Then your constructor could be

```
Item(std::string s) :
    Part_Num(nth_part(0,s)), Dep_Code(nth_part(1,s)), item_Price(nth_part(2,s)) {}
```

However, this would require you to process the string 3 times (which you dont need if you do it in the constructor body). Using the initializer list is good practise, but not always it really pays off.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item(std::string data)
{
  int i=0;
  int counter=0;
  std::string temp="";
  int len=data.length();

  while(i<len)
  {
    if(data[i]!=' ' && i<len-1)
    {
        temp+=data[i];
      }
      else
      {
        if(counter==0) Part_Num=temp;
        else if(counter==1) Dep_Code=temp;
        else 
          {
            temp+=data[i];
          item_price=stod(temp);
          }
        ++counter;
        temp="";
      }     
    ++i;
  }      
}
```

this will give you the desired result for your problem, you can check it by running.